# Getting layer reference using a feature

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Using an existing feature, is there a way/method to get the layer which contains that feature?

Example:

```
# new empty feature which doesn't belong to any layer
new_feat = QgsFeature()

#-------------------------

layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()    
# An existing feature which belongs to a layer
feat = next(features) # feat is connected to active layer

# At this point, how to get layer using feature?
# For example:
print(feat.layer()) # or something
```

Comment: There is no method in the QGIS API for get the name of the layer which contains the feature. Since you identify a layer and then browse through the features in that layer, why don't you query the layer name directly?

Comment: There is [a post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/215550/29431) asking similar question for QGIS 2. I thought there was a short way in QGIS 3. I need to use in Advanced Python field calculator.

Comment: I've added a feature request on "[Getting layer reference using feature](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33871)".